# Web and MobileApp backendsystem in Azure?

Tags: .net, azure, model-view-controller, mobile, azure-mobile-services

Need some input on the architecture for a webapplication .NET MVC and a mobileApp iOS/Andriod. Both need to share the same backendsystem. Is it wise to go with Azure mobile services and then use it for all plattforms? or build a custom WebAPI for the mobileApp?

Any ideas?

Thanks
Jesper

Answer (score 0):

you should use azure mobile services https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/mobile-services/ this is the one stop shop backend for your ios, android as well as windows apps.
Its the full backend with data storage as well as the APIs that you can use in either of the platforms, also with ability to generate the client sdk's.

The backend also helps you with services like push notifications, authentications and Enable offline and sync.

Comment: I would use Azure App Service Mobile Apps these days.  This is a combined Web + Mobile backend.  You can host your ASP.NET web application and then just construct a couple of TableControllers in your code to support mobile and web functionality.  You can then use common models since it's the same codebase.